# How to force auto-completion (on ENTER) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

After I reinstalled VS2017, When I start typing (i.e. `Sys`) then suggestions show up (i.e. `System` is focused):

[image]

However, when I press Enter, it doesn't fill the word, instead it breaks on where i stopped and goes in new line.

If I press ↓ (down key) then the word is highlighted:

[image]
(thus, pressing ENTER after that, makes autofill). However,  the extra keypress is annoying and I'd like that in the first scenario, pressing ENTER made an autofill.

Comment: What if you press the right directional key? Tab?

Comment: To hell with the Tab key; I used to be able to hit Enter to make it happen.

I'm right handed; clicking the Tab key isn't natural when typing.